# Is it reasonable to put all typedefs and forward declarations in one header file in a mid-size project

Tags: c++, header, include

There are many good discussions about `#include`, but finally I did not find an answer on the specific question:

**Is it reasonable to put forward declarations for all classes and all typedefs into one header file for a mid-size project?**

So I could avoid to explicitly making forward definitions at the beginning of each header, and I would automatically have all types available.

Some remarks: I do not use namespaces currently, but that will probably be the next step. Mid-size means, it's maintained mostly by one person and has up to 10000 lines of code / 100 classes. Most of the classes are templates and exist only in a header file.

Structure could then look:

types.h:

```
class A;
template <class T> class B;
template <class T> class C;
typedef C<int> intC;
```

A.h:

```
#include "types.h"

class A{
  public: 
    do_something(intC c);
}
```

B.h:

```
#include "types.h"

template <class T> class B{
  public:
    B(A* a, T val){ ... };
}
```

Comment: Generally, the class author should be the only one who provides forward declarations. For example, `<iostream>` and `<iosfwd>` come from the same library. Users should not write their own forward declarations for third-party libraries, since this is inherently brittle and hard to maintain. If there's a genuine benefit, ask the library vendor to provide forward declarations.

Comment: I'm not talking about a library, I'm just taking about forward definitions of classes in my own project.

Comment: Everything is a library, even your own code. Think in terms of modularization and compartmentalization. You can be your own customer.